# Search through Simulink MATLAB function block code for matching string, from MATLAB command window

Tags: matlab, search, find, user-defined-functions, simulink

I am trying to find a way of searching through the code of a Simulink model's MATLAB function blocks, for a matching string.

For individual MATLAB function files I can simply use `findstr` from the Windows command prompt. However, this does not search through the user defined functions in .slx files (MATLAB function blocks). It works for .m files.

I can do the search manually with CTRL+F in the Simulink model. (CTRL+F -> "View More" -> *Enter search string* -> "Click here to search in current system and below"). This gives me all blocks with user-defined MATLAB functions containing matching strings. I would like to be able to do this via the command window in MATLAB, or the Windows command prompt.

I have tried finding help with Simulink help and spend a while searching the internet without finding anything.

Is there a way of doing this search via code execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to get the handles to all the `MATLAB Function` blocks in your model.  This can be done using

```
blockHandles = find(slroot, '-isa', 'Stateflow.EMChart')
```

Note that `MATLAB Function` blocks are really just a special type of `Stateflow` chart (which ships with `Simulink` without requiring a license for `Stateflow` itself). If you only want the handle to a specific block then you can refine the search using

```
blockHandles = find(slroot, '-isa', 'Stateflow.EMChart', 'Path', gcb)
```

where `gcb` is the name of the block you are interested in.

The text in the function is stored in the `Script` property of the object.  To display it (or write to it) use

```
blockHandles(idx).Script
```

where `idx` is the index indicating which of the blocks you are interested in.  You can use this in a loop to search all of them,

```
for idx = 1:numel(blockHandles)
   strfind(blockHandles(idx).Script,'text_to_search_for')
end
```

Comment: This did the trick! In additon, `strfind` returns the position of the first search string character in the char array that is created as a copy of the function. It seems to use `\n` for line breaks, thus using two characters for each line break.

Comment: what is `slroot()` doing? Is there a way to find only the `EMChart`'s of a specific model? I am always looking for speeding up my code, I would like to get a `Root` object for one specific Simulink model. Do you know of a way?

Comment: `slroot` is just getting the highest level in the Simulink hierarchy.  You could just as easily use `bdroot`, or the name of your model (as a string) to start searching a specific model.

Comment: I might be wrong on that two characters for line breaks. My latest testing is pointing towards only one character. Do not take my word for any of these findings, I might be sloppy.

Comment: Phil, are you sure about that? I have already tried `bdroot` (tried some more just now). It only returns either a char vector with the name of the model, or a numeric (using `'myModelName'`, `gcb`, `gcs` or `gcbh`). Neither of these can be used in `find` used above to set `blockHandles`.

Comment: @Smartskaft2, you are correct.  `slroot` seems to be the only input that works. I can't see an option to refine the search to a specific model, other than only having that model loaded.

Comment: Luckily for my case, where I am building a tool to speed up my daily work, using `slroot` is fast enough. However, I am always trying to create good habits (efficient coding) instead of bad ones.